# mysql structure for dynamic template css (template framework)

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, templates

I'm trying to create a dynamic cssFile.php which retrieves content from DataBase.
with this framework i should be able to change some global css properties and some other properties like Positioning  and Resizing them using html form, but i dont know how to structure data in database and even how to create a good layout.
should database table be like:

```
+-------+------------+---
| color | background | ...
+-------+------------+---
| red   | #fff       |
+-------+------------+---
```

OR like this:

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| class  | property | value |
+--------+----------+-------+
| .class | color    | red   |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: The second one seems to make more sense, maybe replace "class" with "identifier" so you can use Id's, elements and other selectors not just classes

Comment: but how about updating properties
for example one day i set margin: 0px and another day i set it to 10px
it will insert 2 rows and data will be messy and will increase database size

Comment: UPDATE where class=.class and property=property and value=value?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this Layout will be good.

**CSS_type - Table**

```
+--------+----------+
| id     | type     |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | .class   |
+--------+----------+
```

**CSS_main - Table**

```
+--------+----------+-------+------------+
| type   | property | value |  type_name |......
+--------+----------+-------+------------+
| 1      | color    | red   | container  |......
+--------+----------+-------+------------+
```

...